# What are the implications of a race with multiple personalities

Tags: society, science-fiction, races, proto-human

In my universe there is a race of proto-humans known as legionaries. They have a are a minority group and used to be even smaller, only living on one planet in the past. This race used to give birth to litters of 7 children when they bred. However, after a mad scientist released a biological agent into their most prominent water supplies he was able to force their race to mutate and the next generation of this race were the first generation of 'true' legionaries. This new generation did not come out as litters but instead, gave birth to one child with seven fully developed and realised personalities that show prominence at different times.

Since then the previous litter bearing generation has died out and all that remains are legionaries integrating with the rest of society. Aside from the multiple personalities inhabiting the same body at the same time, they have one other biological difference from humans. These proto-humans will rapidly change their body depending on what personality is currently in control. Certain personalities are taller than others, have more muscle mass than others. these changes are not so drastic as to make the new body non-distinguishable from the original, but would instead have the same resemblance a sibling may have. The race is agender as the most drastic change a legionaries can have between personalities is their biological sex itself.

In this question I ask what implications would a race like this have on the rest of society, would much change? What would change as a result? And what would be the likely reaction from other people as a result of these legionaries?

Comment: "What are the consequences of X on society?"-type of questions are always too broad for our standards. Please consider narrowing it down together with removing the opinion based and collateral questions.

Comment: I fear this question is far to broad. They could impact all facets of society, from relationships, jobs, crime and punishment to the philosophical ideas of responsibility and identity. You're really asking at least three questions here, I suggest you split them.

Comment: How long does personality switch take? Do legionaries have any control of the switch? Do all personalities share common memory? Do we need to stick to scientifically plausible switch (preservation of mass etc.), or it can be a Hulk-like transormation?

Comment: As I understand it, the propagation rate went from seven siblings down to one. Do the females give birth just as often, more often, or less often? Seems to me your cociety is in for a huge population decline.

Comment: Also, given the changes that human children and teenagers go through in puberty (growth spurts of inches) in just a few months, if the metamorphosis between personalities occurs over a few months, in a cocoon like state, the physical changes are completely realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Any population with a major cohort capable of personality and physical changes would have an imperative need for the identification of persons.

How that identification would be accomplished will be determined by the technology available to them. For example, tattooing or microchips. Mere identity cards could be inadequate. Although legal and cultural sanctions may overcome so of those difficulties.

Gatekeepers who decide who shall enter and leave houses, residences, buildings, places of work, and commercial premises will be essential.

Essentially, the general changes to a society where many people can change radically will be driven by the need to ameliorate problems of identification and the reduction of harm caused by any of those persons where knowing who did what was important.

The specific methods and techniques will vary according to the society and its technology, but the general principles involved are clear. Identification, tracking and verification will be paramount of such a society.